# SQL group by - merge groups

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Is it possible to "merge" 2 groups obtained after a SQL statement that use group by. For example if I have a field size ENUM('extra-small, 'small', 'medium', 'large', extra-large') and then I run this query `SELECT * from clothes GROUP BY size;`, but for in one case I would like to get in result "extra-small" and "small" in the same group. Is this possible with SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, you can:

```
select count(*) 
    , case size 
        when 'extra-large' 
        then 'large' 
    else size end as grouped_size
from sizes
group by grouped_size
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae3fa/2

Comment: You don't need the CASE expression in the GROUP BY clause, since it uses the aliased name rather than the raw data.

Comment: Sounds good! I will try this. I hope that I can use this with some joins. In reality my DB is more complicated than this simple example. I will let you know how this solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

How about using MySQL [GROUP_CONCAT(expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL
>   values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

Also have a look at [MySQL – The GROUP_CONCAT() function](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/)

Comment: if you use group-concat, you still have to define the group